# how to Reset Column value every 24 hour in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am using node and mongoose and I wish to reset one of the column's value in my database at 12 AM everyday. How could I do that? Any help will be deeply appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) plugin. And write code for update particular field.

Or you can also use Trigger function in Mongo-Atlas